# How to find Address of page to Redirect into that page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, webforms

I'm using **ASP.NET Web Forms** and I want on the click of a button to direct to another page.

Design view:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ShowAllEvents" runat="server" ImageUrl="../../../../_layouts/15/FransabankCalendar/img/all.png" OnClick="ShowAllEvents_Click"/>
```

Code:

```
protected void ShowAllEvents_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect(ResolveUrl("~/_layouts/15/Fransabank/ListEvents.aspx"));
    }
```

The problem is that when I click the button it results in:

> 404 FILE NOT FOUND

I tried also:

```
protected void ShowAllEvents_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Server.Transfer(ResolveUrl("~/_layouts/15/Fransabank/ListEvents.aspx"));
    }
```

But the it gave the same result. What could be the problem?

Comment: Where is the ListEvents.aspx located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 Response.Redirect("~/_layouts/15/Fransabank/ListEvents.aspx");

or 

Response.Redirect("~/layouts/15/Fransabank/ListEvents.aspx");
```

Comment: Why you inserted one thing two time?

Answer (score 1):

If you want address of page

On visual studio find your page  ListEvents.aspx and right click on it select Properties and copy the address you want redirect into that from Browse to URL attribute

```
Response.Redirect("~/_layouts/15/Fransabank/ListEvents.aspx");
```